# Как снять Backwards Compatibility в Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains

Раньше при создании `Activity` был флажок `Backwards Compatibility`, после обновления он исчез.

Answer (score 1):

Панель инструментов и меню можно кастомизировать.

**Правая кнопка мыши ⇒ Customize Menus and Toolbars**.

[image: Customize Menus and Toolbars]

---

Либо в общем меню:

**File ⇒ Settings ⇒ Appearance & Behavior ⇒ Menus and Toolbars**

[image: Menus and Toolbars]